# Calculadora no da soluciones

Tags: c++, funciones

el programa realiza operaciones aritméticas básicas(suma,resta, multiplicación ...) y calcula funciones sen, cos, Ln(logaritmo neperiano. )
la calculadora debe poder validar signos de agrupación para poder calcular expresiones complejas como ((3+5)*14)+ 4*sen(pi))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
double division(char *, char*);
double operador(char *);
bool mapeo2(char*);
bool mapeo(char *);
double detectar(char *);
using namespace std;

int main() {

char ecuacion[100]= " ";
char ecuacion2[100] = " ";
char *ptr;
bool c=false;
double resultado =0;
cout << "Ingrese la ecuacion: ";
    cin.getline(ecuacion, 100);
    strncpy(ecuacion2, ecuacion, strlen(ecuacion));

if(mapeo(ecuacion)){ 
    c = mapeo2(ecuacion);
    ptr = strtok(ecuacion, "()");
    cout << ptr << endl;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        if(c== true){
        resultado = detectar(ptr);
        }else{
            resultado = operador(ptr);
        }

        ptr= strtok(NULL, "()");
    }
}   else{
    resultado=operador(ecuacion);
}

cout << "El resultado es : " << resultado << endl;
return 0;
}


double operador(char *e){ //divide la cadena por operador aritmetico
double result = 0;
for(int i=0; i < strlen(e); i++){
    switch(e[i]){
        case '+':
            result = division(e,"+");
            break;
        case '-':
            result = division(e,"-");
            break;
        case '*':
            result = division(e,"*");
            break;
        case '/':
            result = division(e,"/");
            break;
        case '^':
            result = division(e,"^");
            break;
    }
}
return result;
}


double division(char *ecuacion, char *x){ //divide la cadena por parentesis 
char *ptr;
double result =0;
switch(*x){
case '+':
    ptr= strtok(ecuacion,x);
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        result += atof(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL,x);
    }
    break;

case '-':
    ptr= strtok(ecuacion,x);
    result = atof(ptr);
    cout << result << endl;
    ptr++;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        cout << ptr << endl;
        result -= atof(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL,x);
    }
    break;

case '*':
    ptr= strtok(ecuacion,x);
    result = atof(ptr);
    ptr++;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        result = (result) * (atof(ptr));
        ptr = strtok(NULL,x);
    }
    break;

case '/':
    ptr= strtok(ecuacion,x);
    result = atof(ptr);
    ptr++;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        result = result/ atof(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL,x);
    }
    break;

case '^':
    ptr=strtok(ecuacion, x);
    result = atof(ptr);
    ptr++;
    while(ptr!=NULL){
        result = pow(result, *(ptr+1));
        ptr = strtok(NULL, x);
    break;

    }
}
return result;
}


bool mapeo(char *e){
bool t= false;
for(int i=0; i<strlen(e); i++){
    if((e[i] == '(') || (e[i]==')')){
        t = true;
        i = strlen(e);
    } 

}
return t;
}


double detectar(char *e){ //resuelve funciones de sen,cos, Ln y radicales
int s, c, l, r, ex;
double result=0;
s = strcmp(e, "sen");
c = strcmp(e, "cos");
l = strcmp(e, "ln");
r = strcmp(e, "sqrt");
if ( s ==0){
    result = sin(*(e+1));
}
if ( c ==0){
    result = cos(*(e+1));
}
if ( l ==0){
    if(atof((e+1)) >0){
    result = log(*(e+1));
    }
}
if ( r ==0){
    result = pow(*(e+1),(1.0/ *(e+2)));
}
return result;
}


bool mapeo2(char *e){
for(int i=0; i < strlen(e); i++){
    switch(e[i]){
        case 's':
            return true;
            i= strlen(e);
            break;
        case 'c':
            return true;
            i= strlen(e);
            break;
        case 'l':
            return true;
            i= strlen(e);
            break;
    }
}
}
```

el problema es que la solución siempre da = 0.
disculpen lo largo del código, agradecería mucho su ayuda

Comment: De entrada, tu código da 5 avisos de comparaciones 'deprecated' ( 9 si usamos '-Wall' ). Puede que tengan algo que ver, puede que no.

Comment: No da siempre 0. Las sumas y las restas las hace correctas (estas últimas, con la salida mal formateada).

Comment: ¿Has echado un vistazo a mi respuesta? Con eso corrijo el problema que planteas, que la solución te da 0 (en las multiplicaciones), pero tu código tiene más problemas como que no es capaz de detectar cambios de operador (no es capaz de resolver `4+3-2` por ejemplo) ni agrupar correctamente los paréntesis ni calcular correctamente cosenos, senos, raíces cuadradas ni logaritmos... pero esos son otros problemas (creo que) diferentes.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes muchos problemas en tu código relacionados con la búsqueda de los operandos que intervienen en la operación.

Te arreglo únicamente la operación de multiplicar para que te hagas una idea de qué te ocurre en el código:

```
case '*':
    ptr = strtok(ecuacion, x);
    result = atof(ptr);
    cout << result << endl;
    ptr = strtok(NULL, x);
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        cout << ptr << endl;
        result *= atof(ptr);
        ptr = strtok(NULL, x);
    }
    break;
```

Principalmente, como te dije, no obtienes correctamente los operandos, por lo que siempre obtienes un segundo operando vacío que el `atof` lo traduce como un cero (0), que durante una multiplicación da como resultado 0 sean cuales sean el resto de operandos o bien la división da como resultado infinito por realizar una división entre cero.

Por cierto, si quieres quitarte los mensajes de advertencia de conversión obsoleta, define la función `division` como `double division(char *, const char*);` y posteriormente como `double division(char* ecuacion, const char* x) {`.